# How to save entered strings and integers in C

Tags: c, string, int

Can anyone help me on my code. What it should do is when I enter "create 6 5" its supposed to create a 6x5 rectangular shape with *'s, but will not show yet unless I entered "show".

This is the code i'm working on, it is not correct yet, still figuring out how to do it.

i'm new in programming.

```
char s[100];
    char *s1 = "show";
    char *s2 = "create";


int main()
{
    int zWidth = 0, zHeight = 0, zLoop = 0, aLoop = 0;

    do
    {
    scanf("%s %d %d", &s, &zWidth, &zHeight);

    }
    while (strcmp(s1, s) != 0);

    if(strcmp(s2, s) == 0)
    {
    //To draw the first horizontal line 
    for(zLoop = 0; zLoop < zWidth; zLoop++) 
    printf("*"); 
    printf("\n"); 

    //Drawing the vertical lines 
    for(zLoop = 2; zLoop < zHeight; zLoop++) 
    { 
        printf("*"); 
        for(zLoop = 0; aLoop < zWidth-2; aLoop++) 
            printf("*"); 
            printf("*\n"); 
    } 

    //Last horizontal Line 
    for(zLoop = 0; zLoop < zWidth; zLoop++) 
    printf("*"); 
    printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `do...while` loop will break only when you enter `show` for the `scanf`. Only then will the condition in `while`(`strcmp(s1, s) != 0`) will be false. Once you enter `show`, then `if(strcmp(s2, s) == 0)` will never be true

Comment: `scanf("%s %d %d", &s, &zWidth, &zHeight);` should be `scanf("%s %d %d", s, &zWidth, &zHeight);`. This won't solve your problem though.

Comment: it only breaks when i entered "show" followed by two numbers ie. "show 5 5" and it will not print the *'s

Comment: I removed that if(strcmp(s2, s) == 0) now. it now prints the *'s but only when i entered "show n n".

Comment: That is because the first `do...while` wants the input "show" followed by 2 numbers.

Comment: Try using `while (strcmp(s2, s) != 0);` and then replace `if(strcmp(s2, s) == 0)` with `do{scanf("%s",s);}while(strcmp(s1,s)!=0);`

Comment: `for(zLoop = 0; aLoop < zWidth-2; aLoop++)` should be `for(aLoop = 0; aLoop < zWidth-2; aLoop++) `

Comment: @CoolGuy that worked. thnx! just need to clean it now

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thnx for pointing that out.

Comment: Do you want a rectangle filled? I think that there is no need to split the drawing if it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes i want it filled, can you show me how?

Comment: It is filled (subject to @BLUEPIXY bug report above), but it looks as if the code was copied from a program that printed a hollow rectangle.

Comment: @IAmLaw `for(zLoop = 0; zLoop < zHeight; zLoop++) 
{
    for(aLoop = 0; aLoop < zWidth; aLoop++) 
        printf("*"); 
    printf("\n"); 
}`

Comment: @WeatherVane yes its from a hollowed rectangle, i just modified it so it doesnt look so clean. im not good at looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum command_state {
    SHOW, CREATE, QUIT, HELP, INVALID
};

char Command_line[100];
const char *Show   = "show";
const char *Create = "create";
const char *Quit   = "quit";
const char *Help   = "help";
const char *QMark  = "?";

enum command_state command(void){
    if(fgets(Command_line, sizeof(Command_line), stdin) != NULL){
        char operation[16];
        sscanf(Command_line, "%15s", operation);
        if(!strcmp(operation, Show))
            return SHOW;
        else if(!strcmp(operation, Create))
            return CREATE;
        else if(!strcmp(operation, Quit))
            return QUIT;
        else if(!strcmp(operation, Help) || !strcmp(operation, QMark))
            return HELP;
        else
            return INVALID;
    }
    return QUIT;//input EOF
}

int main(void){
    int rWidth = 0, rHeight = 0, aLoop = 1;
    while(aLoop){
        switch(command()){
        case SHOW :
            if(rWidth == 0 || rHeight == 0)
                printf("execute create is required before\n");
            else {
                int h, w;
                for(h = 0; h < rHeight; h++) {
                    for(w = 0; w < rWidth; w++) 
                        printf("*"); 
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
            break;
        case CREATE :
            if(2!=sscanf(Command_line, "create %d %d", &rWidth, &rHeight) ||
              rWidth < 1 || rHeight < 1){
                rWidth = rHeight = 0;
                printf("invalid create command\n");
            }
            break;
        case QUIT :
            aLoop = 0;
            break;
        case HELP :
            printf(
                "help or ? : this\n"
                "create w h: set to size of rectangle width and  height\n"
                "show      : draw filled rectangle\n"
                "quit      : end of program\n"
            );
            break;
        default : 
            printf("invalid command\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```